# SciPy / Numpy - basinhopping not using initial guess values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to use `basinhopping` to maximize a particular objective function (yes I know it minimizes, I added a negative sign), but when the code is run, it seems to not be starting with the initial guess provided (`x0`), but some arbitrary set of values.

Has anyone experienced this? If so, are there any ways of altering it's behavior?

Comment: IT SEEMS? what do you mean? Be specific.

Comment: I used a callback function within the optimizer to print out current values of x, and this first time it prints, the values are much different than the initial guess values I gave it.

Comment: I see. Show how some code that can reproduce this problem